# USB control of a small water pump

Tags: usb, relay

My son and I are working on building a snake habitat.  We have a Current Orbit Marine LED light (https://x4u6a9v7.stackpathcdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Orbit-Marine-LED-Manual-V5.pdf). The light hub can connect via a micro USB cable to a pump hub (https://x4u6a9v7.stackpathcdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Orbit-IC-with-eFlux-Wave-Pump-Web-Quick-Start-Guide-2.pdf). We don't want to control Current's wave pump, but would like to control a small USB  powered pump (https://smile.amazon.com/gp/product/B01CG2YE6K/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1) in order to make it rain in the habitat. What do I need to do to accomplish this?  Do I need a USB controlled relay such as (https://smile.amazon.com/dp/B01CN7E0RQ/?coliid=I28EQTP5KRNHLO&colid=3HFYILRHYY33E&psc=1&ref_=lv_ov_lig_dp_it)?

Comment: wow, current loop used as a brand name for something dfferent

Comment: Without the details of the electronics inside or the communication method we cant say. That pump hub has multiple outputs which I guess are individually controlled so there is some communication method being used that's not directly usb. So it would not be a simple connection or change you could make.

Comment: The peripherals and controller they provide gives a linear control , but a relay control is just ON/OFF and USB is just 5V.

Answer (score 0):

probably all that you need to do is convert the 24V output from the pump hub down to the 4 to 9V that your rain pump wants. for that a DC to DC converter module like LM2596 or XL5015 seems ideal, if you're not using the wave pump you could use its cable and plug for the connection from from the pump hub to the dc-dc converter.